# Pyspark "TypeError: Cannot convert pyarrow.lib.ChunkedArray to pyarrow.lib.Array"

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, pyarrow, pandas-udf

On Databricks, I have a streaming pipeline where the bronze source and silver target are in delta format. I have a pandas udf that uses the requests_cache library to retrieve something from an url (Which can be quite compute expensive).

As long as there is no big backlog in the bronze table (Low `numBytesOutstanding`), everything goes well. There is a good performance (High processing rate, low batch_duration). Once there is a larger backlog (Due to increasing stream that writes from source to bronze), the performance becomes a lot worse.

At the moment, I keep getting the following error (With different sizes of cluster):
`TypeError: Cannot convert pyarrow.lib.ChunkedArray to pyarrow.lib.Array`
I didn't find a lot about this error, and nothing related to PySpark.
Only [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47963169/typeerror-cannot-convert-pyarrow-lib-chunkedarray-to-pyarrow-lib-array). There it is mentioned that it can be when the size exceeds 2GB, but it is already a few years old, and not Spark related.

I use a pandas_udf, so I assume it has something to do with this. Any one with some ideas?

**Edit:** Not sure if helpful, but here the pandas udf

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

@F.pandas_udf(T.ArrayType(T.ArrayType(T.StringType())))
def get_columns(urls: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
   schemas = []
   session = requests_cache.CachedSession("mySession", backend="memory")
   schema_cache = {}
   for url in urls:
      if url in schema_cache:
         clean_schema = schema_cache(url)
      else:
         schema_raw = session.get(url).json()
         col_occurance = {}
         clean_schema = []
         for col_detail in schema_raw:
            if col_detail[0] in col_occurance:
               col_occurance[col_detail[0]] += 1
               clean_schema.append([
                          f"{col_detail[0]}_{col_occurance[col_detail[0]]}", 
                          col_detail[1]
                       ])
            else:
               col_occurance[col_detail[0]] = 1
               clean_schema.append([col_detail[0], col_detail[1]])
         schema_cache[url] = clean_schema
      schemas.append(clean_schema)
   return pd.Series(schemas)
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug with spark's pandas serialization, here is a simplified repro:

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame, SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.types as T
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
import numpy as np
import pyarrow as pa
import pandas as pd

def large_pandas_udf(iterator):
    for pdf in iterator:
        big_unique_strings = ['x' * ((1 << 20) - 1) + str(i % 10) for i in range(10)]
        strings_list = [big_unique_strings[i % 10] for i in range(1 << 11)]
        arr = np.array(strings_list)
        yield pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['string_column'])

def large_pandas_workaround_udf(iterator):
    for pdf in iterator:
        big_unique_strings = ['x' * ((1 << 20) - 1) + str(i % 10) for i in range(10)]
        strings_list = [big_unique_strings[i % 10] for i in range(1 << 11)]
        arr = np.array(strings_list)
        num_chunks = 20
        chunk_size = len(arr) // 20
        for i in range(num_chunks+1):
            yield pd.DataFrame(arr[i*chunk_size:(i+1)*chunk_size], columns=['string_column'])

def run_udf(spark, udf=large_pandas_udf):
    schema = T.StructType([T.StructField("string_column", T.StringType())])
    spark.conf.set('spark.sql.execution.pyspark.udf.simplifiedTraceback.enabled', 'false') # get full error traceback
    df = spark.createDataFrame([['v']], schema)
    return df.mapInPandas(udf, schema).count()
```

Notice this also includes a workaround -> the idea is to manually chunk up the pandas dataframe small enough so that the pyarrow array doesn't return any "ChunkedArrays". See this pyarrow issue discussing this somewhat confusing behavior: https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/34755

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following configuration to control how many records per batch to process depending on your record size. default the value is 10k.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.maxRecordsPerBatch",100)
```